# Setting datetime values in pandas column: type not converting correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to set the values in a column of a pandas DataFrame to the values of a column in another pandas DataFrame. I am running into an issue where the type (`pandas.tslib.Timestamp`) is not converting correctly.

I have a DataFrame `indicators`:

```
                           0
                   Timestamp
0  2016-02-12 13:45:00-05:00
1  2016-02-16 13:45:00-05:00
2  2016-02-17 13:45:00-05:00
3  2016-02-18 13:45:00-05:00
4  2016-02-19 13:45:00-05:00
5  2016-02-22 13:45:00-05:00
6  2016-02-24 13:45:00-05:00
7  2016-02-25 13:45:00-05:00
8  2016-02-26 13:45:00-05:00
9  2016-02-29 13:45:00-05:00
10 2016-03-01 13:45:00-05:00
11 2016-03-02 13:45:00-05:00
12 2016-03-03 13:45:00-05:00
```

And another DataFrame `signals`:

```
        Signal Timestamp
0    0     NaN       NaN
     1     NaN       NaN
     2     NaN       NaN
     3     NaN       NaN
     4     NaN       NaN
     5     NaN       NaN
     6     NaN       NaN
     7     NaN       NaN
     8     NaN       NaN
     9     NaN       NaN
     10    NaN       NaN
     11    NaN       NaN
     12    NaN       NaN
```

`signals.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 19500 entries, (0, 0) to (1499, 12)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Signal       0 non-null object
Timestamp    0 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 457.0+ KB
```

I try to do:

```
signals['Timestamp'][0] = indicators[0]['Timestamp']
```

which produces

```
        Signal            Timestamp
0    0     NaN  1455302700000000000
     1     NaN  1455648300000000000
     2     NaN  1455734700000000000
     3     NaN  1455821100000000000
     4     NaN  1455907500000000000
     5     NaN  1456166700000000000
     6     NaN  1456339500000000000
     7     NaN  1456425900000000000
     8     NaN  1456512300000000000
     9     NaN  1456771500000000000
     10    NaN  1456857900000000000
     11    NaN  1456944300000000000
     12    NaN  1457030700000000000
```

How do I get this to convert correctly?

Comment: What is your python, numpy and pandas version?

Comment: Python is `3.4.4`, pandas `0.17.1`, numpy is `1.11.0b2`

Comment: OK, what does `signals.info()` show?

Comment: In the past using JSON & Pandas I have found they can vary by an order of 1000.  JSON->PANDAS (1456174020000/1000)/86400 + 25569+(-5/24) gives a 13 digit to a 10 to a date with time stamp.  You may be able to reverse it?

Comment: What if you either (1) convert `signals['TimeStamp']` to a datetime before hand, or (2) delete the `signals['TimeStamp']` column before hand?  I imagine the problem is that you are transferring a datetime into a string and pandas is doing something like converting the datetime to an integer and then string.

Comment: Doing both (1) and (2) works, but I lose the timezone information

Comment: Huh, I don't know why it would work except for timezone...  Well, you could just merge or join.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing

```
signals['Timestamp'][0] = indicators[0]['Timestamp'].set_index('Timestamp').index
```